# c++ Empty template function returns non-empty function pointer

Tags: c++, class, templates, function-pointers

I am confused by the function pointer of the template function.

See

```
#include <cstdio>

class A
{
    public:
        A(){}
        ~A(){}
        void command()
        {
            printf("Cmd");   
        }
};

template<class T>
void cmd_create()
{
    T t;
    t.command();
};

int main()
{
    typedef void(*Funcptr)();
    Funcptr f1 = &cmd_create<A>;
    f1();
    return 0;
}
```

The program output `Cmd`.

The assembly (-O3) shows that

```
    .file   "test.cpp"
    .text
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
    .string "Cmd"
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB38:
    .cfi_startproc
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rsi
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movl    $1, %edi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    call    __printf_chk@PLT
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE38:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Obviously, `&cmd_create<A>` returns the A::command.

The cmd_create is defined as an empty return (**void**), however, the code still gets the `A::command` in such a weird way.

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: What do you mean by `Obviously, &cmd_create<A> returns the A::command.`?  `&cmd_create<A>`1 gives you a pointer to the function `cmd_create` where `T` gets replaced with concrete type of `A`.  That function call `A::command`.  Nothing is returned from either function.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "such a weird way".

Comment: The assembly shows that the code just prints the string "cmd" and I think maybe it is equivalent to returning the command function.

Comment: That's equivalent to modern compilers being very good at inlining code – all the "fluff" has disappeared, but the program has the same observable behaviour.

Comment: The compiler is smart enough to tell that both `A` and `cmd_create` are irrelevant, the only observable result is calling `printf`. Godbolt has easier to digest assembly: https://godbolt.org/z/qKhdvoT3q

Comment: Aha, what you are seeing is called function inlining.  Basically, the compiler is smart enough to know that instead of calling the function at run time, it can just insert the functions code directly into the call site so no function call happens at run time.

Comment: What I mean weird is that why the optimized code prints the "cmd" in a direct way. It seems that the class A and the template function is ignored.

Comment: Thank you! The inlining is a little strange for me considering the assembly code. I will google for more information about the inlining, and thank you for pointing such a key point.

Comment: @Mangoccc A very big part of C++ is performance, so much so that we have a thing called the as-if rule, which states that as long as the observable behavior of the program does not change, the compiler is allowed to transform your code into whatever it wants.  In this case that means inlining the function to save some function call costs.  Other times it could be optimizing a loop out of the code as it can either compute the value the loop would produce or it sees the loop has no observable effect and optimizes it away.

Comment: Looking at the assembly of optimized code rarely exactly matches the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Obviously, &cmd_create returns the A::command.

I am not fluent with assembly, but obviously you misunderstand the code ;).

`&cmd_create<A>` is a pointer to the function `cmd_create<A>`. This function pointer is assigned to `f1`. The pointer is of type `void(*)()`, pointer to function returning `void` and no arguments. No function in the code returns anything (if we do not count `printf` or `main`).

`f1();` calls the function pointed to by `f1`. That is: `cmd_create<A>`. The function creates an object of type `A` and calls its `command` member function which prints the output you see on the screen.

Enabling optimizations means that the compiler emits something that has the same observable behavior. It could emit the same as it would for `int main() { printf("Cmd"); }`.